# Python qrcode module not being saved

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code

If I run this:

```
import qrcode
img = qrcode.make('Some data here')
```

I don't know where it saves the actual image. I've tried CD'ing to a path and run the Python code, I have had the script in a directory. But when running the code above it doesn't create a QR image file in the directory. Where is it saved?!

I've tried running `qr "Some data here" > test.png` from the command-line which works perfectly. But not the module itself for some reason.

Comment: Voting to close because of finding a tutorial criterion. Look at https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/554/how-to-create-a-qr-code-image-or-svg-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The `make` function doesn't output an image. For that you have to do something like this after running that function:

```
img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
```

[Read the docs.](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/)

Comment: It's easier to do: `img = qrcode.make("some data")` and then `img.save("QR.ext")`